# .htaccess RewriteRule behavior with existing subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I've been through many of similar questions but I couldn't find this particular case:

Having this structure:

```
public_html/
   q/
      .htaccess
      index.php
      /dirnofixedname1
      /dirnofixedname2
      /dirnofixedname3
```

- dirnofixednameN are folders that have files to be used by index.php and not to be directly accessible (called like that as I may not enumerate all in the .htaccess file or it would be impractical)
- index.php should process incoming requests

The intention is to process requests like: 
`http://domain/q/dirnofixedname2` with `http://domain/q/index.php?q=dirnofixedname2` while still showing `http://domain/q/dirnofixedname2`. A popular and already solved case indeed.

So that .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

The problem happens that when the request matches those existing directories (thing I want), it works as intended (`index.php` executes and gets `q`) but making a redirect to:

```
http://domain/q/dirnofixedname2/?q=dirnofixedname2
```

(and showing that in the URL bar), instead of the intended:

```
http://domain/q/dirnofixedname2
```

Particularly, if the directory happens to not exist,

```
http://domain/q/dirthatdoesnotexist
```

Gets processed correctly by `index.php` with `q` as `dirthatdoesnotexist` (the script obviously dismisses that and returns nothing).

Do you have any ideas about how to avoid that redirect in cases where the subdir exists? (It's practical to have the same dir name as the parameter)

Comment: Do you have any other directives in htaccess?

Comment: That's all at that directory  (and one in root with Options All -Indexes)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to `DirectorySlash` directive which is by default in `On` state since you are requesting an actual directory in your URI.

You can turn it off by using:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Also to mask directory listing use:

```
Options -Indexes
```

at top of your .htaccess